# Traverse XML with jQuery to get element value

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have some XML that looks like so:

```
<closure1>
  <topClosure>
    <ellipsoidalHead>
      <standardComponentData>
        <variousElements>
        <idNumber>234567</idNumber>
        <nominalThickness units="in">0.3750</nominalThickness>
      </standardComponentData>
    </ellipsoidalHead>
  </topClosure>
</closure1>
<shell>
  <standardComponentData>
    <various_elements>
    <nominalThickness units="in">0.6250</nominalThickness>
    <idNumber>123456</idNumber>
  </standardComponentData>
</shell>
<nozzle>
  <standardComponentData>
    <various_elements>
    <attachedToidNumber>123456</attachedToidNumber>
  </standardComponentData>
<nozzle>
```

In my JS code, I already have the `<nozzle>` element `bomNode` as a jQuery set, i.e.

```
var bomNode = $("nozzle");
```

So, for each nozzle element, I need to

1. Get the value of `<attachedToidNumber>` in the `<nozzle>` element.
2. Find the element that contains the `<idNumber>` that matches
   `<attachedToidNumber>` (`<shell>` in this case).
3. Get the value in the `<nominalThickess>`
   element.

As you can see, the depth of the desired `<idNumber>` element can vary. This is also a very small subset of the whole XML structure, so it can be very large.

I've tried something like this:

```
var attachedToElement = bomNode.parents().find('idNumber').text() === attachedToId;
```

but I get `false` returned. What's the easiest way to get the desired `idNumber` value? I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm just missing it.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I realized that `bomNode` is at the top level, I don't need to go up. a level.  Doing something like this

```
var attachedToElement = bomNode.parents().siblings().find('idNumber')
```

gives me a list of children elements that have an `<idNumber>` element. So, I need to find the one that has the desired value. My thought is to use `.each()`. However, that value is defined outside of the `.each()` function, so I don't have anything to match against. Once I have the list of matches, what's the easiest way to get the set that has the `<idNumber>` value I want?

Answer (score 1):

You were right - you missed a simple thing:

`shell` is not a parent of `nozzle`. They are `siblings`. Try this:

```
var attachedToElement = bomNode.siblings().find('idNumber').text() === attachedToId;
```

But this would return true (if true) - not the actual value.

Comment: Hmmm, ok. However, I still need to go up to the `<nozzle>` element level before getting siblings, so I think it would be something like `bomNode.parents().eq(1).siblings()`, right? And then, how would I get the value for `idNumber` once I find the match?

Comment: I would better go for `bomNode.siblings().eq(1);` but this would return the first from the list of the DOM tree, so not the one that comes up to the `mozzle` element. But this might do the trick - `bomNode.siblings().eq(-2);` - haven't tested this out, so cant guarantee